# select by attribute in a loop with year and month changing arcpy

Tags: select, attributes, arcpy

I have a code as follows, i want select from torn_all layer that date equal to year_month, such as 2009-12 everthing after it will be selected. so i should add 2009-12%. but the year and month are changing.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

years=['2010','2011','2012','2013']
months=["01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12"]



env.workspace="c:/twu/wind/torn/tonardo.gdb"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("torn_all", "lyr")

for year in years:
    for month in months:
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("lyr","NEW_SELECTION",' "date" LIKE "%s-%s%"') %(year,month)
        arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("lyr", "c:/twu/wind/torn/tonardo.gdb/torn_%s/torn_%s_%s") %(year,year,month)
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("lyr","CLEAR_SELECTION")
```

error is 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/twu/wind/code/sep_month_tor.py", line 16, in 
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("lyr","NEW_SELECTION",' "date" LIKE "%s-%s%"') %(year,month)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 6688, in SelectLayerByAttribute
    raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 000358: Invalid expression
Failed to execute (SelectLayerByAttribute).

Answer (score 0):

That method of [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) is getting confused: you're trying to both include a percent sign `%` and call an interpolation operator `%s`. It thinks the `%` is looking for a third argument.

Try instead [`string.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format)

```
'"date" LIKE "{0}-{1}%"'.format(year,month)
'c:/twu/wind/torn/tonardo.gdb/torn_{0}/torn_{0}_{1}'.format(year,month)
```